# Why viewModel not cleared automatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a strange behavior in my application.

I have one navigation graph, and my problem is, when I navigate to Fragment A, the viewModel is created correctly, after that I navigate to Fragment B and then navigate back to Fragment A, although Fragment A `onDestroy` fun called, but the viewModel onCleared fun not, and every objects are the same inside viewModel.

Intesting, but If I navigate from Fragment A to Fragment A1 with an action, so not with the drawer menu, and go back, and after that I navigate again to A1, the A1 viewModel is cleared well. So it is possible that only the main manues affected?

In my another application when I navigate back to Fragment A, `onCleared()` called, and it is the expected behavior for me, I don't know what is the problem with my new implementation.

I use Hilt to DI, and I also use a `BaseViewModel` class, but without it, it does the same problem.

[UPDATE]
When I go back from Fragment B to Fragment A by selecting Fragment A menu item in navigation drawer and after that I go back to Fragment B by nav drawer, Fragment B viewModel doesn't cleared.

But If I first time use that back button to navigate back to the start destination which is Fragment A, and after that I navigate again to Fragment B, Fragment B viewModel is cleared is colled.

`build.gradle`:

```kotlin
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'

    nav_version = "2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Hilt  
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"
```

`VeiwModelInit`:

`private val viewModel by viewModels<ErrorTicketBrowserViewModel>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ViewModel remains in memory until the Lifecycle it's scoped to goes away permanently: in the case of an activity, when it finishes, while in the case of a fragment, when it's detached. so in your case Fragment A is not detached, Fragment A is still existing in the navigation stack and you are navigating back from B to A using pop back stack.

"Starting in Navigation 2.4.0-alpha01, the state of each menu item is saved and restored when you use setupWithNavController" also according to [google documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer) about navigation drawer, the navigation drawer will save the state of each item, that's why you navigate to back to B from the drawer the view model didn't get cleared.

To achieve view model recreation in this case, you can create a function in the view model which reset view model states, and call this function in the top of on `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated` in your fragment

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand, that why my another application doesn't work like this? And how can I achive viewModel re-creation after navigation? Beacause in my workaround not too good to hold states except for example fragment re-creation by rotate phone

Comment: Did you use hilt in your other application ?

Comment: Yes I did, with the same version, and the same set up, this is why I' m confusing, I know that it will be a little peace of code, that make this behaviour

Comment: The problem is caused by the navigation drawer, according to google the navigation drawer save the state of each item. I edited the answer you can try my suggested solution.

Comment: Did you want one viewmodel between all fragments ???

Comment: Thanks, for now I fifured out, that the navigation component update coused this, because my last version there wasn't this behaviour.

Comment: No I didn't want to use the same viewModel, but in this case I have to reset all fields manually, or something similar